# Show error markers in Android Studio sidebar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I can't figure out how to word this, and searching isn't coming up with anything.

Android Studio reports there are errors in my file. I'd like to glance over at the sidebar and see a little red marker to know which line to scroll down to, but there are no error markers, only yellow/blue markers for warnings, todos, etc...

[image]

Is this something that can be enabled in the settings?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a bug; such issues can happen as a result of an exception during background code analysis. Normally error marker are always displayed in the gutter; you don't need to enable anything in the settings.

Comment: You were right. Your response made me look into it. I went into Settings and for some reason the color of the marker for errors/unknown symbols wasn't being used (was unchecked).